# What verb do you use with the word "drain blaster"?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if there's an idiomatic way of using the word **"drain blaster"**. I am thinking of several verbs: **blasted**, **unclogged**, **pushed air into**.

However, I am not sure

> 1. "He blasted air with the drain blaster on the toilet"
> 2. "He unclogged the toilet with the drain blaster"
> 3. "He pushed air into the toilet with the drain blaster"

sound very idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you spelled it, "drain blaster" is not a word. Maybe it is a (brand's) name, or an expression, or a description. To make it a word it would be "drainblaster".

---

From a grammar point of view, all  three sentences are correct. However, communication needs to be not only correct grammatically, but also meaningful and practical. The two latter properties are satisfied successfully by your sentence 2:

> 2. "He unclogged the toilet with the drain blaster"

because it specifies, what you did, what you used, and for what purpose.

If you want to make sure that the listener understands that the operation was successful, you may add some redundancy:

> He **successfully** unclogged the toilet with the drain blaster.